# Global Inbox Super Collider Thingy showing wrong answer count in notification

Tags: bug, status-norepro, global-inbox

So I get a notification in my inbox for answers to my Meta post, like a normal day.

Then I see this:

[image: [this](]

I **demand** to know how SE could do such a thing to cause me to draw freehand circles!

GRUMBLE GRUMBLE GRUMBLE!

[second screenshot of the question to show there are *no* deleted answers from a mod view](https://imgur.com/OuHos)

Comment: Not red enough. and **not** enough jQuery....

Comment: ...and now we all know what answer you upvoted...

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA I kept the style of meta being black.

Comment: @YannisRizos I honestly could care less if my entire vote history was public.

Comment: @TylerShads I couldn't care less if your entire vote history was public either. ;)

Comment: I just had this happen on Arqade on an old question of mine. It said 3 new answers, but only one (of several) was.

Comment: @John I think that might be (although related) a different issue as mine doesn't say "New" just "3 answers".  Still should be addressed nonetheless.

Comment: Ah, I'm mistaken. It doesn't say new. Just "3 answers" though [the question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51287/how-can-i-make-my-villagers-more-pacifistic/80588#80588) has four. 3 of which are old, so AFAIK, there is no reason I should be notified about them again...

Comment: Is your inbox still showing this discrepancy?

Comment: @JarrodDixon Not anymore.

Comment: @Jarrod [It just did it again...](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174/how-can-i-move-a-database-from-one-server-to-another/23156#23156)

Comment: @John your inbox looks correct to me; what were you expecting it to say for that new answer?

Comment: @Jarrod I was expecting "answer on *X*" like my other notifications, not "3 answers on *X*" when there is only one new answer and far more than 3 total.

Comment: @John looking into it - we're seeing the singular "answer on X" in your inbox. Probably something in our redis pipeline (where we store inbox items).

Comment: @Jarrod Ah, well, [I'm still seeing it wrong](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4h6qv.png), and you said to tell you, so... (and yes, I tried the full site from my phone, same problem, can't test on a desktop for several days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't reproduce this - we did have a "blip" in our network aggregation service that might have caused the issue, but it has since been remedied.

Please let me know if you see this behavior again.

Comment: Looks like it just [happened again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160490/inbox-showing-wrong-notification)

Comment: And [another reported instance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160833/182513) of this same situation

Comment: It's definitely [being reproduced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160860) consistently.

Comment: I'll look into it this evening, Eastern time.