# Inbox showing wrong notification

Tags: bug, global-inbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Global Inbox Super Collider Thingy showing wrong answer count in notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143515/global-inbox-super-collider-thingy-showing-wrong-answer-count-in-notification)

I've posted one question on SO today. After a while I saw this:

[image]

It says two answers on the question. But I got only one answer on the question. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053717/read-xml-using-xmlpullparser) is the link to the post. Is this a bug?

Comment: The other answer could have been deleted at some point

Comment: Do you have a new answer notification at the moment for this question?

Comment: @AshRj: That was my first guess too but there is no deleted answer in that question.

Comment: No I don't have any notification for the answer even though it was posted and later deleted.

Comment: @AshRj users with more than 10K can see deleted posts.

Comment: @juergend Oh.. Didnt see ur SO rep. I did see ur MSO rep, hence the confusion

Comment: @Jai please visit [your full inbox](http://stackexchange.com/users/1376202/jai?tab=inbox) and check how many answers you see there for that question of yours.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd this link shows me only one answer to the question

Comment: So like Jarrod says [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144377/152859), this was probably a temporary "blip" in the network aggregation service. Keep an open eye, but I don't think it will happen again any time soon. :)