# How can the answer count in the inbox be wrong?

Tags: bug, global-inbox

I got a notification that there were 4 answers on my recent question. I went and read them, did other stuff, and then thought back "wait, I only saw 3 answers." I'm 10k on meta now, so I would see a deleted one. I went back to the question to check:

[image]

Yes, I see near-dupes but they all have this in common:

- the asker (and answerers) are not 10k and suspect there are deleted questions ( [Inbox showing wrong notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160490/inbox-showing-wrong-notification?lq=1) , [Answer count in Question and in Inbox Incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110471/answer-count-in-question-and-in-inbox-incorrect) )
- no-one can repro - my inbox continues to claim 4 answers many minutes later ( [Global Inbox Super Collider Thingy showing wrong answer count in notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143515/global-inbox-super-collider-thingy-showing-wrong-answer-count-in-notification) )
- speculation that it's counting drafts ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69090/different-number-of-answers-in-global-inbox-and-on-question-page ) maybe hands up anyone who's composing a draft on that question?
- **they have no real answer**

OK so it's not exactly important, but here's a case where it's not deleted answers and it's not a one-time thing that fixes next time the inbox loads, so can anyone solve it?

Comment: I still think this is a duplicate of [Global Inbox Super Collider Thingy showing wrong answer count in notification](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143515/182513).  There was [another question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160490/182513) recently that had the same problem that was closed as a duplicate.  Just because they can't repo it doesn't mean it isn't a bug that they can't find :)

Comment: Caching, pure and simple.

Comment: @ChrisGerken That could only be true if the count used to be 4 and has fallen to 3. But it was never 4. It is 3 now with no deleted answers. And now, 4 hours later, it says 3. Caching of a count that includes drafts, possibly. But it seems pointless and confusing to include drafts in the count.