# Wrong number of answers in notification

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox

In accordance with [Jarrod Dixon's request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144377/222340) I'd like to file another report on the wrong messages in the notifications panel:

---

[image]

---

As one can see, there is a report of 4 answers on my question, while there are only 2. Strangely, the notifications about 2 earlier comments on Andres Caicedo's answer seem to have vanished.

And before one comes to suggest that there may be two answers that were subsequently deleted, let me put in that I left the page open during dinner, and when I got back, there was 1 answer present, and the grey bar mentioned "1 new answer to this question". I have observed in the past that posted and subsequently deleted answers will still increment this counter.

It thus seems that the problem can be summarized as follows:

- The number (in this case, 4) indicates the total amount of events triggered on a question;
- The text following it indicates only of what kind the *last* of these events was.

This obviously leads to discrepancies in case there are events of multiple sorts.

---

I am very much aware that the questions [143515](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160490), [143515](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160490), [160833](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160833) and [160860](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160860) report at least similar issues, if not the same issue, but since I have new information for reproducing this bug I figured it was warranted to create a new posting.

Thanks in advance for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

This is also the case for comments. I will only have one comment, but it tells me I have more than that. Here is an example

[image: 1 commmt]

I have one comment on this post. But the notification tells me I have 3

[image: 3 comments]

Comment: For comments its the number of recent comments on the post, not how many ones you haven't read, in the same way as the dropdown thingymajig gives you recent reputation on a post, not how much extra you've got since you last looked.

Comment: Yep something fishy is going on.

Comment: I think this may be an example of what I mention in my bullet points.