# Incorrect number of answers shown on Notification inbox

Tags: bug, global-inbox

I'm new to this site, so please pardon if anything wrong in my question.

I'm an regular user of **StackOverflow**. I yesterday posted a [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042690/typedef-struct-and-declaring-a-structure-variable/17045597?noredirect=1#17045597) in **StackOverflow**.

For which I got 5 answers. But when I got the 5th answer the notification window showed that I got 10 answer for that question.

[image: SO bug]

I checked that again, I got only 5 answers. Also I looked for the deleted answers, but there is no deleted answer till now.

Then why the notification inbox shows like this ? Is this a bug ?

I checked similar question on meta for different sites(sites like mobile version site, Gardening site etc.). But no-one have answers.

1. [**Mobile Site**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141290/incorrect-number-of-answers-displayed-in-notification)
2. [**Gardening Site**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182542/wrong-number-of-answers-in-notification)

Comment: Deleted answers maybe... Sometimes someone gives a poor answer, gets downvoted and deletes is own post. But 5 deleted answers seems a little bit much.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd: I have privilege to see the deleted votes. There is no deleted answers.

Comment: Could it be including comments possibly in the count?

Comment: @TimStone: I already mentioned about that link in my question. Also there is no answer for that particular question

Comment: @JoshMein: Possibly that can be the case.