# Indicate that there are multiple answers in the notification

Tags: feature-request, answers, notifications, global-inbox

If, say, you get 3 answers to a question in quick succession (low-hanging fruit on SO), the notification bar will show a red **3**, but clicking it only shows **1** new item - the latest answer. It's not clear that there are also other answers, and a new user might not notice them at all.

I'm offering two solutions to this problem:

A) Instead of just saying "answer", indicate "*n* answers". It seems to have worked this way in the old notification bar. (See images in [Wrong number of answers in notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182542/wrong-number-of-answers-in-notification))

B) Make each answer its own distinct notification, with its own link and summary.

This can also be expanded to comments.

Answer (score 1):

> and a new user might not notice them at all

This actually doesn't only apply to new users. I don't consider myself a newbie, but i have also missed answers in some cases. Say, i wake up to 11 notifications, all grouped into 5. I'm not going to count comments to figure out where there might be more than one answer, and so i end up missing something.

This is especially noticeable when they receive different scores.